# How to number propositions by part in beamer?

Tags: beamer, numbering, theorems

My presentation has three parts about three different papers. I would like to number the theorems and propositions within each part (paper).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your required usage. It just helps in getting more accurate answers for your usage.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, to make the `\part` command reset the recounter(s):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\pretocmd{\part}{\setcounter{theorem}{0}}{}{}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part One}
\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
Test theorem in part one.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
Test proposition in part one.
\end{proposition}
\end{frame}    

\part{Test Part Two}
\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
Test theorem in part two.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
Test proposition in part two.
\end{proposition}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

[image]